# How replace values from one numpy array by other array with indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays and one list with indices

Array source (array 01):

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Array with new values (array 02):

```
y = np.array([11, 22, 33])
array([11, 22, 33])
```

and a list with indices

```
a = [1,2,1]
[1, 2, 1]
```

I need to replace the values of array 02 in array 01 based on indices

The return expected:

```
array([[1, 11, 3],
       [4, 5, 22],
       [7, 33, 9]])
```

How to do this without loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a nice coincidence that previous SO question with `numpy` tag also [discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252964/other-form-to-index-in-python) quite a similar question

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing):

```
x[np.arange(len(x)), a] = y
```

I found also [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) easier for me than official documentation.

Comment: @Fernando this is because Python loops are slow and `numpy` actions are actually internal loops done in C level.